# Add extra value before save serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My form sends data to django-rest-framework, but the form contains two fields, and I want to save 5 fields in the database, other fields I calculate on my own (they are not sent by the form). How can I add additional values before saving?

**so, form send 'user' and 'comment' values, I want add 'article', 'ip_address' before save to DB**

models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Articles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Comment'))
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(_('IP address'), max_length=50)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Publish'), default=False)
```

serializers.py

```
class CommentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.first_name')

        class Meta:
            model = Comments
            fields = ('user', 'comment')
```

views.py

```
class AddCommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comments.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentsSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override `create()` method:

```
class CommentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ('user', 'comment')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        new_comment = models.Comment()
        new_comment.user = validated_data['user']
        new_comment.comment = validated_data['comment']
        new_comment.article = get_your_article_somehow()
        new_comment.ip_address = get_your_ip_address_somehow()
        new_comment.save()

        return new_comment
```